# Form tag error when trying to render repeater control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting the form tag error ( ...must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server. at System.Web.UI.Page.VerifyRenderingInServerForm...) when attempting to render the html of my repeater.

The call to render:

```
System.Text.StringBuilder stringbuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
StringWriter stringwriter = new StringWriter(stringbuilder);
HtmlTextWriter htmltextwriter = new HtmlTextWriter(stringwriter);
rptEvaluation.RenderControl(htmltextwriter);//repeater control

content += stringbuilder.ToString(); //content is a string variable.
```

The page and code behind work fine without the rendering component.

Any thoughts?

Thanks, Adam.  Here's my repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptEvaluation" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptEvaluation_OnItemDataBound">
<HeaderTemplate>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Category Name</th>
</tr>
</HeaderTemplate>

<AlternatingItemTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfCatID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>' />
<tr style="background-color:#eee;">
<td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<asp:Repeater ID="rptCategoryQuestions" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Question ID</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <th>Student score</th>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionID") %></td>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblScore" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Approaching" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Meets" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Exceeds" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>    
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionID") %></td>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblScore" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Approaching" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Meets" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Exceeds" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>    
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                     </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
        </tr>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>

<ItemTemplate>
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCatID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("CategoryId") %>' />
        <tr style="background-color:#666;">
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Category") %></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptCategoryQuestions" runat="server">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                            <th>Question ID</th>
                            <th>Question</th>
                            <th>Student Score</th>
                            </tr>
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionID") %></td>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblScore" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Approaching" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Meets" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Exceeds" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>    
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfQuestID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("QuestionID") %>' />
                            <tr>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "QuestionID") %></td>
                                <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Question") %></td>
                                <td>
                                    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblScore" runat="server">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Approaching" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Meets" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>    
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Exceeds" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>    
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                               </td>
                            </tr>
                     </AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        </table>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
<FooterTemplate>
     </table>
</FooterTemplate>
```

'

Comment: What is rptEvaluation?  Is it within a form?

Comment: Yes, I am building a dotnetnuke module and the rptEvaluation is in an .ascx file housed in the page form.

Comment: Can you post the section where rptEvaluation is?

Comment: And that is within a <form> tag right?

Comment: Well, and maybe I am going about this wrong.  It is within a <form> tag like all asp pages are.

Comment: Does the form tag have runat="server" attribute?

Comment: Yes, it does, however because it is a dotnetnuke module, the form tag looks like this: <dnn:Form ID="Form" runat="server" ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data">.  Maybe there is a devil in that detail.

Comment: @LucasSmith Did you ever get to the bottom of this or find an alternative? I have the same problem.